# I could not display dynamic input fields with values when the page loads?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
try{
//Need to make a connection
$con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=courseraassignment","root","");


$statementUpdate=$con->prepare("select * from position 
                   where profile_id=:profile_id");
$statementUpdate->execute(array(
    ':profile_id'=>$_REQUEST['profile_id']
));
foreach($statementUpdate as $row){
   echo $row['year'];
   echo $row['description'];
   echo "<br>";
}
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo "error".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

From this PHP code, I wanted to achieve data including the year and description of the position table from the database.

Here is my complete html code:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Ashiful Islam Prince's Resume Registry</h1>


<h1>Editing Profile for UMSI</h1>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['profile_error'])) {
    $error = $_SESSION['profile_error'];
    unset($_SESSION["profile_error"]);


    echo '<span class="text-danger">';


    echo $error;


    echo '</span>';
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <p>First Name:
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php
        echo $firstName;
        ?>"
        ></p><br>

    <p>Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php
        echo $lastName;
        ?>"</p>

    <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php
        echo $Email;
        ?>"</p><br>
    <span class="text-danger">
<?php
if(isset($email_sign_error))
    echo $email_sign_error;

?>
</span>


    <p>Headline:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="headline" value="<?php
        echo $Headline;
        ?>"</p>


    <p>Summary:<br/>
        <textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="80">
    <?php
    echo $Summary;

    ?>
</textarea>
    <p>Position : <input type="button"  class="add_position" id="add_position"
                         name="addPosition" value="+">
        <div class="position_fields" id="position_fields">

       </div>
    <p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="btn" class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
 </p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the part of code from above:

```
<div class="position_fields" id="position_fields">

   </div>
```

In this part, I want to show these fetched values(The year and the description).

Here is my JQUERY code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var countPos=0;
    var add_button=$('#add_position');
    var wrapper=$('#position_fields');
    window.console && console.log('Document ready called');
    //When the user clicks on the add button then It inserts these input fields
    function addField(event){

        if ( countPos >=9 ) {
            alert("Maximum of nine position entries exceeded");
            return;
        }
        countPos++;
        window.console && console.log("Adding position "+countPos);
        $(wrapper).append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'"> \
    <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
    <input type="button" value="-" \
        onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
    <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
    </div>');
    }
    $(add_button).click(function(event){
        addField();
    });
    addField();



    });

   </script>
```

This code is developed for handling the dynamic input field issues. When the user clicks to the add button then dynamic input fields will be displayed and these fields will be shown at the time of page loads as well.

I want to achieve:
Everything will be done as same as it is. But when the page loads these dynamic input fields will be displayed with values. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You'll have to use [$statementUpdate->fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) for your foreach!

Comment: Would you propose an answer? I could not catch your comment properly.

Comment: To be honest: no! I just caught this major error and would have to check your whole script. But maybe it's more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Ok, please check, and If it is possible then propose an answer.

Comment: I've proposed a more suitable place for your question. Your script most probably has various issues. fetchAll() itself should be straightforward with the documentation.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222140/discussion-between-ashiful-islam-prince-and-csabinho).